# MySQL Syntax error while creating stored function

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting a syntax error on executing the below function in MySQL.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FABC (P_MEMBER_EMAIL VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS int 
BEGIN
DECLARE RESULT int;
DECLARE V_DATE DATE;
SELECT DOJ+365 INTO V_DATE FROM CHYK_MEMBER_MASTER
WHERE UPPER(MEMBER_EMAIL)=UPPER(P_MEMBER_EMAIL) AND SUBSCRIPTION='Y';
IF V_DATE>SYSDATE THEN
SET RESULT=1; 
ELSE
SET RESULT=0; 
END IF;
RETURN RESULT;
END;
```

The error is as follows "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Not sure what's causing this. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a delimiter that will tell MySQL the END of the function definition.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `FABC`(`P_MEMBER_EMAIL` VARCHAR(30)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE RESULT int;
DECLARE V_DATE DATE;
SELECT DOJ+365 INTO V_DATE FROM CHYK_MEMBER_MASTER
WHERE UPPER(MEMBER_EMAIL)=UPPER(P_MEMBER_EMAIL) AND SUBSCRIPTION='Y';
IF V_DATE>SYSDATE THEN
SET RESULT=1; 
ELSE
SET RESULT=0; 
END IF;
RETURN RESULT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```